# How to enter a uint256[] function input in java script?

Tags: web3js, contract-design, contract-invocation

I'm trying to interact with my smart contract using java script. My function uses an uint256[] input.

In python the desired input would be input = [1,2]

In java script I tried

```
        const arrayindex = ["1","2"];
```

and used arrayindex as input for the function

This however gives me the error:

```
Error sending transaction: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="0", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.5)
```

So how do I correctly input the desired input?

Comment: add the function code

Answer (score 0):

In Java the uint256[] parameter will be converted to List<BigInteger>

I used the Web3j tool to automatically convert contract JSON to Java

Answer (score 0):

It might depends on what javascript library you are using to interact with your contract, but normally, `const numbers = [1,2,3]` should work.